# Why does Azcopy append 'pwd' in target path when copying from Azure Blob storage to local drive?

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azcopy

I am trying to copy the file from Azure blob storage file share to local drive using azure cli.

Below is the command I am using

`azcopy copy 'https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/fileshare/myBlobDirectory/file.txt' 'C:\myDirectory\file.txt'  --recursive`

It fails to copy and when I see the log in .azcopy folder it tries to access the target path as

`/home/rohanjadhav/C:\myDirectory\file.txt`

Basically in every local path that I am providing the `pwd` is getting appended in the initial.

I have logged in to azure env using terminal and azure cli.

I have tried appending the SAS key as well. tried the command

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, using the same command as yours and I can see that the file is downloading in the respective location with `C:\myDirectory\file.txt` as file name but not recognizing it as path.

[image]

This is the reason why you are receiving your file path as `/home/rohanjadhav/C:\myDirectory\file.txt`.

To make this work, you can give the folder name with respective to your azure cli storage i.e., /home/rohanjadhav. Below is the complete script that worked for me.

```
azcopy copy 'https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.file.core.windows.net/<FILESHARE_NAME>/<FILE_NAME><STORAGE_ACCOUNT_SAS_TOKEN>' '/home/swetha/2505'
```

[image]

Here the file copies from fileshare to azure cli storage with same name as file share.

#### Update

If you are trying to download file from FileShare to your local machine then you need to use the command `azcopy` from your command prompt(you need to download Azure CLI to your local machine) rather than portal's Azure CLI since both have different storages. I reproduced the same and could the expected results as below.

##### command

```
azcopy copy "https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.file.core.windows.net/<FILESHARE_NAME>/<FILE_NAME><STORAGE_ACCOUNT_SAS_TOKEN>" "C:\myDirectory\sample.txt"
```

##### Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is 2505? It should be local C drive right?

Comment: @RJ it is a random folder I created where the files from file share will be copied.
If you are doing in Azure portal's CLI then it will maintain a separate storage where in all the files are stored in `/home/<Name>`.

Comment: `azcopy copy 'https://<STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME>.file.core.windows.net/<FILESHARE_NAME>/<FILE_NAME><STORAGE_ACCOUNT_SAS_TOKEN>' '/home/swetha/2505'`

This command is copying file from fileshare to azure-cli homedir but I want it to be saved in my local machine like C drive or D drive.

Comment: @R.J,  Its just that you need to perform the same command from your command prompt(Azure CLi) rather than performing it in Azure CLI. Also do check my updated answer.

Comment: Is it never possible to achieve this by running the command from Azure CLI? I have been trying to automate some process wherein created bash script on azure cli and need to download the file.

Comment: You can but again that needs manual work which can be downloaded from portal's Azure CLI as mentioned in this image https://i.imgur.com/ooX51Wi.png. After downloading it from portal you can find the same file in your preferable local downloads location.